# Fix the "Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate arguments with this function" error when creating a calculated field

Tags: aggregate, aggregate-functions, tableau-api

I need to create a Dimension (calculated field) that depends on a filter.

My dataset has four columns: **ID** (Int), **Variable Name** (String), **Value** (Int) and **Client ID** (String). For each client ID there will be a value for each type of variable.

There are 6 types of Variable Name, and for each row there is unique ID.

I'm using a filter by Variable Name so there is one, and only one variable type available at the same time.

In order to display it in a stacked bar chart by that dimension, I have created this calculation field (In reality if has six IFs, but I'll use just one to illustrated it):

```
IF ATTR([1 (ML_Output)].[Variable Name])= "Interest Rate" THEN [Interest Rate] END
```

That way, when the filter is in "Monthly Interest Rate", the ATTR function should show the only type of variable available in the Variable Name field, which would be "Monthly Interest Rate". The problem is that it shows the "Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate arguments with this function" error.

I've been trying to solve this with many tutorials, but none of them work for one reason of another.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

PS: The original calculation that was doing what I wanted used a Parameter. However, since parameters won't update automatically when the dataset changes, I can't use it anymore. The original calculation was:

```
IF [Parameter 1]="Interest Rate" THEN [Interest Rate] END
```

I need the calculated field as a dimension. So, if I aggregated the result of the calculation, then it would be a measure, and that can't be used to create a stacked bar.

Comment: is [Interest Rate] an aggregated field?

Comment: No, it's not aggregated. I could aggregated that field with ATTR(), which I have tried, but the result is not working since I need a non aggregated field to created the stacked bars.

Comment: Just added an example that was originally working.

Comment: Since [Interest Rate] is not an aggregation then you don't need the ATTR() around the first part. This should work then: IF [1 (ML_Output)].[Variable Name] = "Interest Rate" THEN [Interest Rate] END